# What would have happened if WCKD had killed out all of the Gladers?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

As in the ***Maze Runner***, the **Gladers** are in the **Maze Trials** and the whole point of the maze is to try and escape.

Because Kids kept on being killed, and in the movie **half** of the Glade was wiped out by the **Grievers**. What would have happened if the gladers never found a way out if **Thomas** and **Teresa** never found it out and Thomas never stung himself?

Comment: Please put it into an answer, please do not comment if you feel like you have nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCKD would have drained the bodies of most of the enzyme they could, and considered this maze group a failure. They would continue their plans with the other mazes. Unlike the books that only had 2 mazes with a goal of dissecting the best teen out of a handful for scientific information, the movies have multiple mazes and hundreds of kids, that we know of. No hint of how many more they were running. Here WCKD thought of the gladers like cows for milking. No individual glader is particularly important compared to the entire group, ***as far as the movies have shown.***

Comment: Do you have any sources to back you u on your train  of thought?

Comment: Mainly everything we see in Scorch Trials.  The conversation between Ava and the game of thrones actor while Thomas snuck into the draining room. The countless gladers in the compound after Thomas group was "rescued".

Comment: What would have happened to the Gladers that tried to escape or didn't make it back to the Glade before the doors closed and after they were killed?

Answer (score -1):

If WICKD killed out all the Gladers, they would not be able to continue and conduct Phase 2 and so on. The whole point of WICKD experimenting on the Gladers was so they could find the strongest of the groups to help stop the Flare. Therefore, WICKD would fail their mission.